# Remove unnecessary horizontal/vertical spaces in highchart bubble chart

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I am using highchart to show bubble chart. Everything is working fine except in many cases there are lot of horizontal space(below min cirlce and above max cicle) and vertical space(left of lowest x and right of highest y). Because of this issue my chart sometimes seems very crowded even though there are some free space left in chart. I tried setting min/max of x/y axis but then it then clipped top/left circle. Is there any way i can instruct highchart to use all space in chart to draw bubbles.
I have created sample script at

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/ftghd9ny/1/`
```

In this demo you can see extra vertical space. X axis is showing fine. In some other cases there are extra space along x axis.

Comment: Can you replicate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I have updated question with fiddle link

Comment: You can adapt extremes on yAxis by [min](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min) / max parametr or use [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions) / [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner)

Comment: Using min/max clipped circle on edges by half. I tried setting tickPositioner  but unable to find any exact appropriate min/max value which can show all circle. Is there any way i get size of circle so that i can then increase/decrease min/max value on axis